# Question about the normal bundle of a totally geodesic submanifold of a Cartan-Hadamard manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm reading the exposition in Lang's *Fundamentals of Differential Geometry* of the following generalization of the Cartan-Hadamard theorem:

Suppose $X$ is a Cartan-Hadamard manifold (i.e. a complete, simply connected manifold with everywhere nonpositive sectional curvature) and $Y$ is a complete totally geodesic submanifold of $X$. Let $NY$ be the normal bundle of $Y$ in $X$, and let $\exp_{NY}: NY\rightarrow X$ be the restriction of the exponential map to $NY$. Then $\exp_{NY}$ is a diffeomorphism. This is Theorem 2.5 of Chapter X.

I'm confused about a detail in the proof of the preceding Theorem, 2.4. Fix $y_0\in Y$, and for each $y\in Y$, let $P_{y_0}^y$ denote parallel transport from $T_{y_0}X$ to $T_{y}X$ along the unique geodesic connecting $y_0$ to $y$. Now, define the smooth map $E:Y\times N_{y_0}Y\rightarrow X$ by $E(y,v)=\exp_y(P^y_{y_0}v)$.

At the bottom of page 273, Lang claims that $dE_{(y,v)}(z,0)$ is orthogonal to $dE_{(y,v)}(0,w)$ for any $y\in Y,v\in N_{y_0}Y,  z\in T_yY,w\in N_{y_0}Y$.

I don't understand why this is true. He says it follows from the Gauss Lemma (Lemma VIII.5.6), but I can't figure out how it follows. I'm probably missing something simple. Does anyone know why those things are orthogonal?

Also, Lang is the only reference I can find for the fact that $\exp_{NY}:NY\rightarrow X$ is a diffeomorphism. Does anyone know if this exists elsewhere in the literature?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a basic fact about Jacobi fields. I recommend reading about Jacobi fields in books such as Cheeger and Ebin's Comparison Theorems in Riemannian Geometry (which probably has a proof of the Cartan-Hadamard Theorem too) or other more modern books on Riemannian geometry.

Comment: @Deane Yang 
So, I accidentally asked this question from a temporary account...

Would you mind explaining a bit how this comes from the basic theory of Jacobi fields?
I figured one could do this by looking at two Jacobi fields $J_1,J_2$ along $t \mapsto \exp_y(tP^y_{y_0}v)$, one given by varying $y$ in the direction $z$ and the other given by varying $v$ in the direction $w$.
Then we want to show that $F(t)=\langle J_1(t), J_2(t) \rangle$ is identically 0. $F(0)=0$ and $F'(0)=0$, so suffices to show $F''(t)\equiv 0$. $F''(t)$ is an expression involving the curvature, and isn't obviously 0...

Comment: Let $\Gamma(\cdot, t)$ a family of geodesics, so that for each $t$, $\Gamma(\cdot,t)$ is a geodesic. Also, assume that $\Gamma(\cdot,t)$ is parameterized by arclength. Let $S = \partial_s\Gamma(s,t)$ (which has length1) and $T = \partial_t\Gamma(s,t)$. Now differentiate $S\cdot T$ a couple of times with respect to $s$. Now use that partials commute and the definition of Riemann curvature, as well as its symmetries.

Comment: @Deane Yang
This will show that if $S(0,0)\cdot T(0,0)=0$ and $S(0,0)\cdot \frac{D}{\partial s}T(0,0)=0$, then $S(s,0)\cdot T(s,0)=0$ for all $s$,
but this isn't what I need in this case (unless I'm missing something.)

In my case, I have two families of geodesics $\Gamma_1(s, t) = E(y, s(v+tw)) $, and $\Gamma_2(s,t) = E(\beta(t),sv)$, where $\beta$ is a curve through $y$ with tangent vector $z$.
I want to show that $ T_1(s,0)\cdot T_2(s,0) = 0$ for all $s$,
where $T_i = \partial_t\Gamma_i(s,t)$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at the result carefully enough. I also don't see why the two Jacobi fields need to remain orthogonal. It seems to me that you have to prove that a set of linearly independent Jacobi fields remain linearly independent along a geodesic. I'm pretty sure this is worked out very nicely here: Heintze, Ernst; Karcher, Hermann 
A general comparison theorem with applications to volume estimates for submanifolds. Annales scientifiques de l'École Normale Supérieure, Sér. 4, 11 no. 4 (1978), p. 451-470

Comment: I just looked this up in Cheeger-Ebin, which I recommend you look at. You just have to prove that the differential of the exponential map is injective. But the differential simply maps a nonzero tangent vector to $NY$ to the value of the Jacobi field generated by that tangent vector. Applying the Rauch comparison theorem to the corresponding Jacobi field on flat Euclidean space tells you that the Jacobi field is nonzero.

Comment: @Deane Yang
Notation as in Cheeger-Ebin, Theorem Rauch I requires that $V(0)$ be tangent to $\gamma$ and Theorem Rauch II requires that $V'(0)$ be tangent to $\gamma$.
The results in the paper of Heintze and Karcher are about Jacobi fields with $V(0)=0$ and $V'(0)$ normal to the submanifold.
I don't think any of these assumptions apply here.

Comment: I would advise not trying to apply the theorems exactly as they are. Rather, adapt the proofs to your specific situation. Roughly, if you have a Jacobi field along a geodesic in flat space and another one in negatively curved space, both with the same initial data, then one in the negatively curved space will have larger norm than the one in flat space.

Comment: @Deane 
Thanks for the useful comments!
I've worked out a proof that the exponential map is a diffeomorphism and have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not sure about that detail in the proof in Lang,
but here's a slightly different proof that $\exp_{NY}:NY\rightarrow X$ is a diffeomorphism.

*Step one*: $\exp_{NY}$ is surjective.
To see this, let $x\in X\setminus Y$. Let $B$ be a closed metric ball centered at $x$ containing some point of $Y$.
Since $X$ is complete, $B$ is compact, and since $Y$ is closed in $X$, $B\cap Y$ is compact.
Thus, there is $y_0\in B\cap Y$ which is closest to $x$, and so we have $d(x,y_0) = d(x, B\cap Y) = d(x, Y)$.
By differentiating $y\mapsto d(x,y)$ along any curve in $Y$ through $y_0$, we find that the geodesic connecting $y_0$
to $x$ is normal to $Y$ at $y_0$. In other words, if $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ is the geodesic with $\gamma(0)=y_0$, $\gamma(1)=x$,
then $\gamma'(0)\in NY_{y_0}$. So $\exp_{NY}(\gamma'(0))=x$, and we have surjectivity.

*Step two*: $\exp_{NY}$ is injective.
Suppose there were distinct $v_0, v_1 \in NY$ such that $\exp_{NY}(v_0) = \exp_{NY}(v_1)=x$.
If $v_0,v_1$ were based at the same point of $Y$, then the exponential map based at that point would fail to be injective,
contradicting the Cartan-Hadamard theorem. So $v_1, v_2$ are based at distinct points $y_1,y_2\in Y$.
Let $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow Y$ be the geodesic with $\gamma(0)=y_0, \gamma(1)=y_1$. 
Then we have $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}d(x,\gamma(t)) = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=1}d(x, \gamma(t))=0$,
because the geodesic connecting $y_0$ to $x$ is normal to $\gamma'(0)$ at $y_0$ and
the geodesic connecting $y_1$ to $x$ is normal to $\gamma'(1)$ at $y_1$. This contradicts 
the convexity of the distance function of $X$.

So $\exp_NY$ is bijective.
As Deane pointed out in the comments, it now suffices to show

*Step three*: The differential of $\exp_{NY}$ is everywhere injective.
For this, fix $y_0\in Y$, and for each $y\in Y$, let $P_{y_0}^{y}$ denote parallel transport
from $y_0$ to $y$. Then the map $Y\times NY_{y_0} \rightarrow NY$ given by $(y, v)\mapsto P_{y_0}^y v$
is a diffeomorphism, so it suffices to show that the map $E$ defined as the composition $Y\times NY_{y_0} \rightarrow NY \stackrel{\exp_{NY}}{\rightarrow}X$
has everywhere injective differential.
To this end, choose $(y,v)\in Y\times NY_{y_0}$ and nonzero $(z,w)\in T_yY\times NY_{y_0}$.
We need to show $dE_{(y,v)}(z,w)\neq 0$. Let $\gamma(t)$ be the geodesic passing through $y$ at time 0 with velocity $z$.
We need to show that $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} \exp_{\gamma(t)} P_{y_0}^{\exp(\gamma(t))} (v+tw)$ is not zero. Let 
$\alpha(s)= \exp_y P^{y}_{y_0}(sv)$.
Let $\Gamma(s,t) = \exp_{\gamma(t)} P_{y_0}^{\exp(\gamma(t))} s(v+tw)$, and 
$J(s) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Gamma(s,0)$. $J$ is a Jacobi field along the geodesic $\alpha$. Set $f(s) = \langle J(s), J(s) \rangle$. We will show $f(s)>0$ for $s>0$. 
Setting $s=1$ will then yield the desired result.

Compute 
\begin{align*}
f'(0) &= 2\langle \frac{D}{\partial s}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Gamma(0,0), \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Gamma(0,0) \rangle\\
       &= 2\langle \frac{D}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\Gamma(0,0), \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Gamma(0,0) \rangle\\
       &= 2\langle \frac{D}{\partial t}|_{t=0}P_{y_0}^{\exp(\gamma(t))} (v+tw), \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\gamma(t) \rangle\\
       &=2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{t=0} \langle P_{y_0}^{\exp(\gamma(t))} (v+tw), \frac{d}{dt}\gamma(t) \rangle\\
       &=0,
\end{align*}
since $P_{y_0}^{\exp(\gamma(t))} (v+tw) \in NY$ and $\frac{d}{dt}\gamma(t)\in TY$ for all $t$.
Also,
\begin{align*}
f''(s) &= 2\langle J'(s), J'(s)  \rangle + 2\langle J''(s), J(s) \rangle\\ &= 2\langle J'(s), J'(s)  \rangle - 2\langle R(\alpha'(s), J(s))\alpha'(s), J(s) \rangle\\&\geq 0.
\end{align*}

Now, $J(0) = z$, so if $z\neq 0$, then $f(0)>0$, which combined with the two computations above, proves $f(s)>0$ for all $s>0$.
If $z=0$, then $w\neq 0$ and $J'(0)=w$, so $f''(0)>0$, and again we conclude $f(s)>0$ for all $s>0$.

Comment: I haven't looked at your proof carefully, but it looks like what I had in mind. I recommend, when possible, figuring out your own proofs like this. The paper by Heintze and Karcher, as well as other papers by Karcher, helped me a lot when learning this stuff. I recommend looking at the papers by Jost and/or Karcher cited here: http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1992-333-01/S0002-9947-1992-1052910-2/S0002-9947-1992-1052910-2.pdf